# doubly linked list gets stuck when it gets to merge sort - java

Tags: java, sorting, merge, doubly-linked-list

I'm storing a random generated numbers in a doubly linked list. If there's more than 5 integers that are greater than 50, I'm going to merge sort the linkedlist. The problem is that the program work but when it gets to the merge sort part, it never terminates and I can't figure out why.

Here's my code: The merge sort is implemented above my main.

```
        import java.util.Random;
        import java.util.Scanner;

    public class DLinkedList<E> {




  private static class DLinkedNode<E> {
         private int item;
         private DLinkedNode<E> prev;
         private DLinkedNode<E> next;

         private DLinkedNode(int rand) {
           item = rand;
           next = null;
           prev = null;
         }

     private DLinkedNode(E value, DLinkedNode<E> prev, DLinkedNode<E> next) {
       item = (int) value;
       this.next = next;
       this.prev = prev;
     }
   }
protected DLinkedNode<E> head;
protected int size;
private static Scanner in;

  private void verify(boolean mustBeTrue) {
    if (! mustBeTrue) {
      throw new java.lang.AssertionError("assertion error");
    }
  }

  private void checkInvariants() {

    verify((size == 0) == (head == null));
    verify(size >= 0);
    if (size == 0) {
      return;     // no more checks
    }
    int measuredSize = 0;
    DLinkedNode<E> node = head;
    do {
      node = node.next;
      measuredSize++;
    } while (node != head);
    verify(measuredSize == size);
  }


  public DLinkedList() {
    head = null;
    size = 0;
    // one of the constructor's jobs is to make sure that the invariants hold.
    checkInvariants();
  }


  public boolean add(int rand) {
    checkInvariants();
    DLinkedNode<E> newNode = new DLinkedNode<E>(rand);
    if (head == null) {
      head = newNode;
      newNode.next = head;
      newNode.prev = head;
    } else {
      DLinkedNode<E> tail = head.prev;
      tail.next = newNode;
      head.prev = newNode;
      newNode.next = head;
      newNode.prev = tail;
    }
    size++;
    checkInvariants();
    return true;
  }


  private DLinkedNode<E> nodeAtPosition(int index) {
    verify (index >= 0);
    DLinkedNode<E> result = head;
    while (index > 0) {
      result = result.next;
      index--;
    }
    verify (result != null);
    return result;
  }


  public int remove(int index) {
    checkInvariants();
    if ((index < 0) || (index >= size)) {
      String badIndex =
        new String ("index " + index + " must be between 0 and " + (size - 1));
      throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(badIndex);
    }
    verify (head != null);
    int value = head.item;
    if (size == 1) {
      head = null;   // very simple!!
    } else {
      DLinkedNode<E> node = nodeAtPosition(index);
      value = node.item;             // return the value
      if (index == 0) {              // removing the head node
        head = node.next;            // new head node == old second node
      }
      node.prev.next = node.next;    // get this node out of the list
      node.next.prev = node.prev;
    }
    size--;
    checkInvariants();
    return value;
  }
//////////////////////////////// MERGE SORT
  public DLinkedNode<String> merge_sort(DLinkedNode<String> head) {
        if(head == null || head.next == null) { return head; }
        DLinkedNode<String> middle = getMiddle(head);      //get the middle of the list
        DLinkedNode<String> sHalf = middle.next; 
        middle.next = null;   //split the list into two halfs

        return merge(merge_sort(head),merge_sort(sHalf));  //recurse on that
    }

    //Merge subroutine to merge two sorted lists
    public DLinkedNode<String> merge(DLinkedNode<String> a, DLinkedNode<String> b) {
        DLinkedNode<String> dummyHead, curr; 
        dummyHead = new DLinkedNode<String>(size); 
        curr = dummyHead;
        while(a !=null && b!= null) {
            if(a.item <= b.item) { curr.next = a; a = a.next; }
            else { curr.next = b; b = b.next; }
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        curr.next = (a == null) ? b : a;
        return dummyHead.next;
    }

    //Finding the middle element of the list for splitting
    public DLinkedNode<String> getMiddle(DLinkedNode<String> head) {
        if(head == null) { return head; }
        DLinkedNode<String> slow, fast; slow = fast = head;
        while(fast.next != null && fast.next.next != null) {
            slow = slow.next; fast = fast.next.next;
        }
        return slow;
    }
  //////////////////////////////////////////////// 

  public String toString() {
    checkInvariants();
    DLinkedNode<E> node = head;
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    if (head != null) {
      while (true) {
        result.append (node.item);
        node = node.next;
        if (node == head) {
          break;    // entire list has been traversed
        }
        result.append (" ==> ");
      }
    }
    checkInvariants();   // make sure we didn't break anything
    return result.toString();
  }






  public static void main (String [] arguments) {

        Random rnd = new Random();
        in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int listCount;
        int countgrtr50=0;

        DLinkedList<String> dll = new DLinkedList<String>();
        System.out.println (dll);

        System.out.print("Enter number of integers: "); 
        listCount = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter range: "); 
        int range = in.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < listCount; i++)
        {
            int rand = rnd.nextInt(range)+1;
            dll.add(rand); 
            if(rand>50){
            countgrtr50++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println (dll);
        System.out.println ("more than 50: " + countgrtr50 );

        if (countgrtr50>5){
            System.out.println ("sorting... ");

            dll.merge_sort(dll.head);
            //dll.remove(1);
            System.out.println ("after: "+dll);
        } else {
            // error if less than 5
            dll.remove(4);
            System.out.println ("else after: "+dll);
        }

      }



}
```

This is the result I get:

```
Enter number of integers: 20
Enter range: 100
60 ==> 36 ==> 12 ==> 44 ==> 11 ==> 61 ==> 27 ==> 86 ==> 55 ==> 51 ==> 5 ==> 44 ==> 39 ==> 18 ==> 23 ==> 50 ==> 73 ==> 49 ==> 96 ==> 82
more than 50: 8
sorting...
```

and then it doesn't terminate, but when the integers greater than 50 are less than 5, it works fine cause it doesn't sort or anything.

Comment: What debugging techniques have you tried? https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I tried debugging your code on Netbeans. It turns out that when running for 100 integers with 101 of range, the first time I get into the method `getMiddle` there is an endless loop on the `while`. I see that you are linking the end of the list with the beginning of it based on the `add`method. On the `add` method you verify when you get back to the original head of the list, but not in the `getMiddle`. I would recommend you to try not linking them directly but rather using two `head` and `tail` variable references inside your class.

Answer (score 0):

Because sometimes you assume your list is circular, and sometimes not. In your add, checkInvariants and toString methods, you assume head comes after tail (tail.next = head and head.prev = tail). However, in your merge and getMiddle methods, you assume that null comes after tail (tail.next = null). That's why your getMiddle methods ends up in an infinite loop, as neither fast.next nor fast.next.next becomes null.

My suggestion is, make your head.prev = null and tail.prev = null. Also, you should have a reference to tail when building a doubly linked list.

Comment: Should that be tail.next = null? Also as noted, merge() only updates next pointers and expects next pointer == null to indicate end of a list. I would suggest leaving merge() as is. Just before the mergesort, change the last node's next pointer to null, and sort the list as a single linked list. After the sort, make a pass over the list to set the previous pointers, and set the pointers so it's back to a circular list.

Comment: Yes, tail.next should be null. Also, merge_sort should be left as is, but merge should be changed to maintain prev pointers as well. The data structure should be consistent even if prev pointers aren't used.